# Android Studio Fragment Incompatible types Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();
    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.home,frag,"text msg");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

When i try to run this apps, it shows an error and i have no idea what's going on.

gradle file has the following version

```
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Anyone can help ? Please refer to the screenshot .Thx

[image]

Comment: use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for v4 type use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of the one you have used `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the support libraries (see your imports) you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`